# Apache Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: apache, tomcat, server

I linked Apache with Apache Tomcat and last night, it was working fine until when I tried running the system again today, it gave me an access denied error. My Apache server has the mod_security in it configured with OWasp rules. Here's the error log:

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 1). Match of "within {tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required [file "C:/SourceCodes/Apache24/conf/owasp-modsecurity-crs-master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "31"] [id "960032"] [rev "2"] [msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "GET"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/XSS_Attack_Test/"] [unique_id "VQ67McCoAWwAABg4SGoAAAA@"]  
[Sun Mar 22 20:53:05.769945 2015] [:error] [pid 6200:tid 1084] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 1). Match of "within %{tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "C:/SourceCodes/Apache24/conf/owasp-modsecurity-crs-master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "31"] [id "960032"] [rev "2"] [msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "GET"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/favicon.ico"] [unique_id "VQ67McCoAWwAABg4SGsAAAA@"]
```

Comment: Surely the error log did not contain this on a single line. Please [edit] so that we can read it better.

Comment: Which part of the log you don’t understand?

Comment: A lot of it. I'm new to Web Development.

Comment: I meant the log should be formated exactly as you see it. Breaking a single log line is almost as bad as joining multiple log lines together.

Comment: It's in a text file.

Comment: From what the log containts I guess there are only two lines (two line feed characters). Edited. Now it is obvious you didn’t include first part of the first log line.

Comment: There are two log entries, two requests. Both via the GET method of HTTP. One to `/XSS_Attack_Test/`, one to `/favicon.ico`. Both blocked by some rules in `C:/SourceCodes/Apache24/conf/owasp-modsecurity-crs-master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

The error log clearly stat that which rule is violated, you may see the rule ID in the log and disable it.

disable the rule by the ID, use the below segment in the mod_security.conf

SecRuleRemoveByID 960032

Answer (score 0):

Just commented some of the rules in http policy to make it work.